# PHP +issue with the file_get_contents and comparing the value

Tags: php, comparison, file-get-contents

This is driving me nuts. I have a test.html file that contains either "OPEN" or "CLOSED" inside of it. I do a `file_get_contents()`:

```
$testA = file_get_contents ('files/test.html');

if ($testA == 'OPEN') {
  $color1 = '#00800';
  $back1 = '#DDFFDD';                        
}
else {
  $color1 = '#FF0000';
  $back1 = '#FFD9CC';                        
}
```

It returns false even if the value in my test.html = OPEN.

Using `$testA = "OPEN";` works just fine. I'm a newbie, so I know its something simple that I'm overlooking. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: How did you create that file? Which encoding does it have?

Comment: `var_dump($testA)`, show us *exactly* what you're getting.

Comment: var_dump($testA) = string '<html><body>CLOSED</body></html>' (length=32)

Comment: Then there you go. It's not `OPEN`. It's `<html><body>CLOSED</body></html>`.

Comment: Can you post what `echo "--".$testA."--"` gives?.. This should give --OPEN-- as answer, if there is any space or any other character then prob is with the test.html page content..:)

Comment: And how does the string `'<html><body>CLOSED</body></html>'` look like it equals `'OPEN'`?

Comment: <html><body>CLOSED</body></html> != OPEN, There's your problem.  You could change the content of the file so that it only contains the string - or you could do an strpos instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$testA = file_get_contents ('files/test.html');

if(strpos($testA, 'OPEN') !== FALSE){
    $color1 = '#00800';
    $back1 = '#DDFFDD';                        
}else{
    $color1 = '#FF0000';
    $back1 = '#FFD9CC';                        
}
```

*Edit*
You can read more about [strpos() here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).